# Minimize time for snow-covered image with `i.atcorr` module

Tags: raster, grass-gis

Did anyone notice the time taken by `i.atcorr` module when running for a snow-covered image?

It is noticed that two to three hours for 30m resolution with the image of 3656*1000 size.

Both for VNIR(60bands) and SWIR(256 bands) it is taking a long time. What could be the reason?